# Ban outgoing traffic from docker container

Tags: docker

Can I forbid all outgoing traffic from a docker container except a http proxy server, without sophisticated configuration of `iptable`?

I don't want this container to access any network at all, exception AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD:80. Is there any convenient way to achieve so?

EDIT:

I found that using `--internal` can do the trick, and link it to a proxy server container on the same host would allow traffic. Is this method secure though?

Comment: Yes that is what you should be using

Comment: @TarunLalwani I am just a bit concerned about this approach. There are other services running on the same machine (not on docker tho), that can absolutely not accessed by containers.